# Dynamically create a file from PHP

Tags: php

I am cycling through an unknown number of JSON files, reading the contents, adding the information I want to variables, then I want to write that information into separate files.

Here is my code:

```
$directory = '../filepath\*';
// For each file in the directory that is found, 
// place it in an array with the variable $file
foreach(glob($directory) as $file){
    // For each file found, get the contents
    $JSONContents = file_get_contents($file);
    // Now that we have the contents, decode it from JSON into and array so PHP can read it
    $JSONDecode = json_decode($JSONContents, true);

    $person= '';
    $information= '';

    // Now for each file that has been decoded,
    // find the person data and display the person ID and information
    foreach($JSONDecode['SMSData']['datainfo']['data'] as $value){
        $person = $value['person'];
        $information = $value['information'];
        // If $person is not empty, create a file, else, do nothing
        if($person != ''){
            file_put_contents('../filepath/somewhere'.$person . '.txt', $information);
        } else {
            //do nothing!
        }
    }
}
```

I am wanting to create each file with the `$person` id and put the `$information` inside the file but I don't think that I have the format to save the files correct.

Edit: I should point out that I am not getting any output from this.

Comment: What is your output, when run this code?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I am not getting any output.

Comment: Put in a debugging statement inside the foreach and see if it is even entering it.  Add some additional echo's to pinpoint what worked and what didn't.

Comment: Did you try to encode information? Try this `echo file_put_contents('../filepath/somewhere'.$person . '.txt', json_encode($information));` Note: the `echo` added for checking. In success the `file_put_contents` method returns number of characters written to the file.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I worked what the problem was, some person id's were numeric and some weren't. So changed the `if` statement to `is_numeric($person)` then handle them differently to the rest. Also my filepath was wrong!